# Flask sendmail not showing any errors, but no email received

Tags: python, flask

I have a Python Flask app setup and running on CherryPy (hosted on [Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/), OS: Debian GNU/Linux 7.0). I'm using [Flask Sendmail](http://flask-sendmail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to send mails, ran the app and tried sending the email, it does not show any errors and executes properly. But there's no email received (checked Spam and every other folder).

Any help? I've added the code below.

Configuration for Flask app:

```
app.config.update(
    DEBUG=True,
    MAIL_DEBUG=True,
    MAIL_FAIL_SILENTLY=False,
    MAIL_SUPPRESS_SEND=False,
    DEFAULT_MAIL_SENDER='Tester',
    TESTING=False
)
```

Email sending part:

```
mail_handler = Mail()
mail_handler.init_app(app)

try:
    msg = Message("Hello World",
                  recipients='jane@doe.com')
    msg.html += '<b>HTML content for email</b>'

    if mail_handler!=None:
        mail_handler.send(msg)
        print "email sent"

    return {"status": "success", "message": "Please check your email"}

except Exception as e:
    return {"status": "failed", "message": "Failed"}
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I've spent the whole evening with this thing too. The working mail module I finally got is below:

```
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

mail = None

def configure_mail(app):
    # EMAIL SETTINGS
    global mail
    app.config.update(
        MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
        MAIL_PORT = 465,
        MAIL_USE_SSL = True,
        MAIL_USERNAME = 'blabla@gmail.com',
        MAIL_PASSWORD = 'mega_password',
        DEFAULT_MAIL_SENDER = 'blabla@gmail.com',
        SECRET_KEY = 'abcdefd_thats_a_charming_secret_key',
    )
    mail=Mail(app)

def send_email(subject, sender, recipients, text_body, html_body):
    msg = Message(subject, sender = sender, recipients = recipients)
    msg.body = text_body
    msg.html = html_body
    mail.send(msg)
```

Then I simply invoke the implemented method from the proper places:

```
from emails import send_email # 'emails' is a name of the module provided above
send_email('messageTopic', 'blabla@gmail.com', ['blabla@gmail.com'], 'composedMsg', None)
```

And don't forget to invoke congiguration code before sending emails. E.g.:

```
from emails import configure_mail # 'emails' is a name of the module provided above
app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
configure_mail(app)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not looking for an SMTP solution. I just have to send emails, not receive any.

Comment: Well, an email cannot be sent without using any mail server. And in order to work with it (gmail server in my case), I use this protocol. My code is also used to only send emails, not receive.

Comment: (a reply to removed comment) Then as far as I understand you want your client to be the only endpoint (the mail server itself). I'm not sure if it's possible... E.g. what do you expect to be seen in the 'sender' field in the recipient's mailbox? Usually it's noreply@blabla.com. But if you're working on your own mail server (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_transfer_agent), then I certainly can't help. Correct me if I'm wrong somewhere. Good luck :)

Comment: I spent 4 hours just trying to figure this out... thanks for your response

Comment: @user3152311 glad it was helpful even in the end of 2019!